# rm adding extra backslash to variable

Tags: linux, bash, rm

I'm writing a very simple script, that will interact with my git repository, but I've reached a point, where I can't figure out why the following is happening.

Having:

```
destPath='~/Dropbox/Shared/Alex\&Stuff'
destFile='file.zip'

#git archive --format zip --output $destFile master

echo $destPath/$destFile

rm $destPath/$destFile
```

The echo outputs the correct path:

> ~/Dropbox/Shared/Alex\&Stuff/file.zip

But the rm fails with the following:

`rm: cannot remove ‘~/Dropbox/Shared/Alex\\&Stuff/file.zip’: No such file or directory`

So, why the extra backslash is added when `rm` is executed? `Alex\\$Stuff` instead of `Alex\$Stuff` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tilde character needs to be outside quote to be expnded:

```
destPath=~/Dropbox/Shared/Alex\&Stuff

destFile='file.zip'

#git archive --format zip --output $destFile master

echo "$destPath/$destFile"

rm "$destPath/$destFile"
```

Comment: Dumb mistake, as always. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. I made similar mistakes many times in my code and then spent hours to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 destPath="$HOME/Dropbox/Shared/Alex\&Stuff"
```

Tildas do not always expand to $HOME. And the ampersand doesn't need the backslash, unless you want an actual backslash there.

As for the double backslash, I would guess that that's how `rm` quotes its internal strings (i.e., backslashes have special meaning and a single backslash needs to be written as '\'--C does it this way, for example)

Comment: Sorry, this is not a guessing game. Either you _know_ the answer or you don't. If you don't, please post a comment instead.

Comment: "the ampersand doesn't need the backslash" ... within single quotes.

Comment: It doesn't need a backslash within double quotes either in bash. Only if it were unquoted would it need one.

Comment: @arkascha This is not a guess. Tildas don't expand to  $HOME if they're quoted. They only do if they're at the beginning of an unquoted string.

Comment: Sorry, but from the way you wrote it appears to me as if you are more or less guessing. If that is not the case, then please write more specific ("do not always" - so when not? / "I would guess" - you are _really_ _not_ guessing?)